# How get files list from remote GitLab with Groovy

Tags: git, jenkins, svn, groovy

I used this code (below) in jenkins to get files list  from svn url. 
After that, I migrate SVN to GIT with keeping jenkins and groovy to get files list from a remote. So I want to update this code to use git instead svn. Any help ?

```
def values = [ ]
def command = ['svn','list','https://<svn_url>']
def proc = command.execute()
proc.waitFor()
proc.in.eachLine{
    values.add(it.substring(11, it.indexOf(".properties")))
}
return values.reverse()
```

Comment: Are you using a free-style job in jenkins in which you execute this script?
And how do you deal with credentials?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files

Answer (score 0):

If the Groovy script is executed while the Git repository is already checked-out, then, as commented, [`git ls-files`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) is enough.

It would do like a `svn list [URL[@REV]]` (which lists the files and directories of the repo URL at revision rev, rev defaulting to the head revision, URL defaulting to the
repo URL of ".")